# Menu with multiple checkable items

Tags: menu, selection, multi-selection

I'm a developer and that means that I cannot do UX. I would like some feedback on something I am trying to do, look at this:

[image]
Now, this is a menu item with sub-items. I would like to be able to do 2 things here:
When the user click on some user, I open the report for that user. Nice, clean and obvious. But I would like to be able to select more than one user and show the combined report of them. I just cannot think in a way to make this nice and easy to understand. How can I make the user clearlly understand that he can both click on just one (and this would unselect all and open just the clicked) or check multiple users?

I would like to avoid have to use CTRL or SHIFT + Click, this should work on smartphones and tablets too). To me, the obvious thing is to put a checkbox in front of the user. Click on the name, it goes only for it, click on the checkbox, the report filters to all the checked. But maybe there is an more elegant way? I mean, since I'm a developer, it must exist something better, right? :D

(The color on the icon is important for the report.)

**Edit 1:**
I ended up doing what Max suggested, the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put checkboxes in front of each option, and a separate 'View' link or button at the end of each item row (i.e. a 2 column arrangement). At the bottom of the column of checkboxes have a button labelled "View selected".

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCd1dB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If it is a long list of options, you could add a count to the View selected button label that would increment as you check each box.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fthqgQ.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

how about a check box to the right of all the users (aka a multi select)

and at the top generate combined reports. make it generate individual report if they only select on and if its multiple put generate combined reports

[image]

and maybe above option one or on the top you put generate reports.

Comment: This is good, because it avoids the problem of the user having two different routes to generate the report.